# Are static utility methods not pure Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: java, oop, static-methods

People say Static utility methods are bad in OOP because they don't follow the OOP way of doing things.

I know static utility methods come from the more traditional procedural programming paradigm. And people say true OOP would be modelling the real world in objects sense encapsulating state & behaviour into one.

Is this true?

If so, is it best practice in modern OOP to not use static utility methods at all? Or is it still common to use them?
Would this latter question be more of a 'depends' situation?

Comment: Static methods are probably non-OOPish, but nobody says that you absolutely must write totally OOPish programs. You should write good programs combining the appropriate technologies. OOP is not always the best thing to achieve the result.

Comment: Slavish adherence to any design pattern or principle will lead you astray.

Comment: Use static methods where it makes sense. Period. As the guys above me said - write good code with the appropriate tools.

Comment: To paraphrase @Kevin Krumwiede "Slavish adherence to any design pattern is itself an anti-pattern."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static methods (without side-effect) are in Computer Science named **functions**.

And I think it is general consensus that Functional Programming is superior.

Object Oriented Programming has the advantage that **state** is imminent to it, and in comparison to FP can make things more straight-forward.

However in the case of static methods functions are fine. Fine for low-level values. If the case is many functions operating on more complex classes, one may have an issue. Maybe those classes are unnecessarily complex, the logic too convoluted.

Compare BigDecimal with a theoretic version with static methods for add, multiply and so on. Functions would probably be better readable.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, static utility methods are against the OOP paradigm.  Should you use them?  That depends on how much a purist you want to be, among some other things.  Some people even [call them evil](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html) :)

I think it's great that you are asking this question, though.  The more you know about OOP, and the difference between it and the other paradims of software development, the better informed you are when choosing between alternatives.